# How to setup crontab from su in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

i have an issue trying to setup crontab for a user with a new ubuntu image, basically i'm trying to automate crontab jobs in a bash scriipt that contains the following

```
# (crontab -u user -l ; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello") | crontab -
```

an important thing here is i need to do this as su always for specific reasons, and i got the following error :

no crontab for user

this is because in the folder /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ there is not a file for the user, i supposed that this file is created automatically when you edit crontab with option (-e) but I'm trying to avoid it because i need to do this in a bash script, any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron tabs should be located under:
 in the /etc file.
 If you want a file to run as the root user then create a new file and place it under /etc/cron.d
 For example I have a backup file as follows:
 It is named backup and placed in the above folder

`PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin`

```
#min hour dayOfMOnth Month DayOfWeek

0 0 * * * root invoke-rc.d atop _cron
```

The 0 specifies the time in min then hour and * specifies all time.
So:
12 3 5 1 7 root command would run on the at 3:12 on the 5th in January on the 7 days of the week.
 Then specify the user you want to run the command and then the command.

[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto][1] should give a a pretty good idea how to set it up.

In short make a file placing it in the folder with owner and group settings as root with r/w for root and r for group and all other users.
 Thanks,
 Donald

Comment: thanks this is what im lookin for

Answer (score 0):

To setup a crontab for a user as root, try doing that.

```
echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello" | crontab -u user -
```